# Why "Window Leaked" is caused by Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dialog

I have an AlertDialog in my activity and at the end of activity i want to start another activity.
The problem is that i can't click Dialog buttons (to do other operations) because Dialog disappears immediatly. **If i remove the intent all works fine.** I have put `dismiss()` in `onStop()`,`onPause()` and `onDestroy()` to cancel dialog, but seems do not effect. 
Also i can't start intent in Dialog because i must do necessarily other operations before to start new activity.
I don't understand where is the problem...
This is the function to create Dialog:

```
  public AlertDialog createDialog(){
    AlertDialog alert = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckAvailability.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("This is a repeating event.");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.warning2);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save for this event only", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            event = false;
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Save for future events", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            event = true;
        }
    });
    alert = alertDialog.create();
    return alert;
```

I create and show dialog:

`AlertDialog alertDialog2;
 alertDialog2 = createDialog();
 alertDialog2.show();`

And at the end of activity i want to start another activity:

```
    //alertDialog2.dismiss(); <-- with or without this line the effect is the same
Intent intent = new Intent(CheckAvailability.this, Homepage.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

These are the activity method:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("METODO", "onDestroy");
    if ( alertDialog2!=null ){
        alertDialog2.dismiss();
    }
}
    @Override
       public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
        Log.d("METODO", "onPause");
        if ( alertDialog2!=null){
        alertDialog2.dismiss();
    }
}
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("METODO", "onStop");
    if ( alertDialog2!=null ){
        alertDialog2.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I haven't log, simply the Dialog immediately disappears and the app continues showing the next activity. But if i remove the activity methods (`onStop,onDestroy,onPause`) i have this log:

```
12-02 12:10:27.317    2938-2938/com.example.simone.consulenzeapp E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.ACTIVITY.CheckAvailability has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{531162cc V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-684,262} that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.ACTIVITY.CheckAvailability has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{531162cc V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-684,262} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
        at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.ACTIVITY.CheckAvailability$ClickHandlerConfirm.onClick(CheckAvailability.java:131)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    at com.example.simone.consulenzeapp.ACTIVITY.CheckAvailability$ClickHandlerConfirm.onClick(CheckAvailability.java:131) -----> is line: alertDialog2.show();
```

Comment: Not sure I understand but I would do my dismiss call before calling super.#### in those methods. Also, I don't think you need onDestroy or onStop if you have it in onPause. Finally, you can call "isFinishing()" on the activity before doing the dismiss so that you don't try to do anyting with the dialog after the main window has gone away.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain better the "finishing" solution?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29